# Python: rsync exclusions not working in script, works in bash shell

Tags: python, subprocess, quotes, rsync

Below is a script I am using to test a problem.

Running an rsync command via subprocess.check_call does not work in excluding files obtained from an exclude variable.

I am printing the result of the command from Python, editing it and then running it in a bash shell directly as a comparison and it fails to exclude my exclusions when using Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.1

import subprocess

exclude = 'exclude_me_dir, exclude_me_file.txt'
source_path = '/tmp/source'
path_to_backup_file_name = '/tmp/destination'
engine_options = '-axh --delete --delete-excluded'

def rsync_backup(source_path, path_to_backup_file_name, exclude, engine_options):
    exclusions = ['--exclude="%s"' % x.strip() for x in exclude.split(',')]
    rsync_command = ['rsync'] + exclusions + engine_options.split() + [source_path + '/', path_to_backup_file_name]
    print(rsync_command)
    return subprocess.check_call(rsync_command)


rsync_backup(source_path, path_to_backup_file_name, exclude, engine_options)
```

This is the output of the Python script and running the rsync command directly.

```
> pwd
/root
> ls /tmp/source/
exclude_me_dir/  exclude_me_file.txt  file1.txt  folder1/
> /tmp/rsynctest.py
['rsync', '--exclude="exclude_me_dir"', '--exclude="exclude_me_file.txt"', '-axh', '--delete', '--delete-excluded', '/tmp/source/', '/tmp/destination']
> ls /tmp/destination/
exclude_me_dir/  exclude_me_file.txt  file1.txt  folder1/
> rsync --exclude="exclude_me_dir" --exclude="exclude_me_file.txt" -axh --delete --delete-excluded /tmp/source/ /tmp/destination
> ls /tmp/destination/
file1.txt  folder1/
```

N.B. As I was about to post this I discovered the problem appears to be the double quotes in '--exclude="file"' as if I remove them it works.  I tried escaping them like so '--exclude=\"file\"'. but this does not work either.  I require the double quotes for occasions when a space occurs in a file name or directory.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the double quotes are the problem, don't escape them, just drop them.

They are just required on the shell to hinder the shell from expanding.

Moreover: If you escape them the way you've shown, they are only escaped on the python level where it makes no sense, because double quotes are automatically escaped inside of single quotes

```
In [2]: '\"foo\"'
Out[2]: u'"foo"'
```

it should be

```
In [3]: '\\"foo\\"'
Out[3]: u'\\"foo\\"'
```

Comment: I was just about to answer my own question that it works to exclude files/folders with spaces without using the double quotes, i.e. '--exclude=%s' but you beat me to it :).  Accepted, Thanks